# How do car remote lock works?

Tags: infrared

How do car remote control work? On what medium do they communicate? How do the transmitter and receiver communicate?  Is it blue tooth, infrared or any other kind technology?

Comment: What are your electronic skills like - "how does something work" requires knowledge of YOU in order to provide an appropriate answer. What is "weekday medium"?

Comment: I have no knowledge of hardware. I'm a software engineer. Corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way Radio Frequency broadcast of an encrypted rolling key protocol. Both receiver and transmitter are paired to the same keyset, and the receiver checks for n through n+64 or so keys transmitted by the remote (just incase the button is pressed a couple of times, to prevent desyncing.).

Comment: What do you mean by "the receiver checks for n through n+64 "?

Comment: @kashifkhan that the receiver will accept a certain number of valid keycodes from the remote.

Comment: @kashifkhan that the receiver will accept a certain number of valid keycodes from the remote.